# More than one listenFor tag in Speech Macro XML

Tags: xml, macros

I recently started getting into windows Speech Macros, it allows you to make custom commands for windows Voice Recognition. Currently, I've only been able to say 1 thing to it, and it could respond and do the command, but I want it to be like OK GOOGLE, where I first say its name, then its ready for the actual command, unless I say CANCEL, here is an example of what I have:
(my system is called J-SIB and it refers to me as Vulpix.JS)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<speechMacros>
  <command>
    <listenFor>Jay Sib, Start Chrome</listenFor>
    <speak>Yes Sir, Mister Vulpix Dot Jay Es</speak>
    <run command="C:\Users\Programming\Desktop\Chrome.exe"/>
  </command>
</speechMacros>
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<speechMacros>
  <command>
    <listenFor>Jay Sib</listenFor>
    <speak>Yes Sir?</speak>
   <listenFor>Start Chrome</listenFor>
   <speak>Yes Sir, Mister Vulpix Dot Jay Es</speak>
   <run command="C:\Users\Programming\Desktop\Chrome.exe"/>
  </command>
</speechMacros>
```

How could I get it where I don't say the command in one long-wind? Because whenever I try the command above, it says there is an error.

> "Element 'listenFor' is unexpected according to the content model of the parent element 'command'. Expecting: sendKeys, insertText, run, emulateRecognition, waitFor, speak, alert, confirm, setTextFeedback, script, wmpMediaPlay, WmpMed..."

(you may be asking whats wrong with saying the whole command, I just don't really like it, I want it to be like OK GOOGLE)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't have the tags in that order. All the `listenFor` tags have to be next to each other and any of them will trigger the same command.

You will probably need to split it into two commands like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<speechMacros>
  <command>
    <listenFor>Jay Sib</listenFor>
    <speak>Yes Sir?</speak>
  </command>
  <command>
   <listenFor>Start Chrome</listenFor>
   <speak>Yes Sir, Mister Vulpix Dot Jay Es</speak>
   <run command="C:\Users\Programming\Desktop\Chrome.exe"/>
  </command>
</speechMacros>
```

Comment: Didn't work, it recognized both of those as 2 different commands :/

Comment: Yes, that is because they are different commands.  You still haven't answered what error you got with your one, but I suspect that you can't have multiple speaks in a single command and multiple listenFor are just treated as equivalents (i.e. any of them will trigger the command)

Comment: oh sorry, didnt see that you asked what the error was, here it is:
"Element 'listenFor' is unexpected according to the content model of the parent element 'command'.
Expecting: sendKeys, insertText, run, emulateRecognition, waitFor, speak, alert, confirm, setTextFeedback, script, wmpMediaPlay, WmpMed..."

Comment: Basically it is telling you that you can't have the tags in that order.  All the listenFor's have to be next to each other and any of them will trigger the same event. So I think my solution above is the closest you will get. waitFor was a possibility but that is just a wait timer.  Not sure what the confirm action does, but I think it just expects OK.